# How to match any text upto the last comma?

Tags: regex

I am trying to match all the text in the following line

`is a frozen account. To create / edit transactions against this account, you need role,`

excluding the last comma using this regex

`.*?[,]`

but this gives the following matches

`is a frozen account. To create / edit transactions against this account,`

`you need role,`

What am I missing here?

Comment: `.*?` is lazy, it will try to find the *shortest* possible match.

Comment: redited the question. sorry for the mishap. I need to exclude the last comma from the match

Comment: @FelixKling But keep in mind, that in some cases a lazy `.*?,` will ALSO match a `,` with the `.*?` expression. If it has the choice to go "greedy" in order to produce a match vs *stay lazy with no match*, it will go greedy!

Comment: @dognose: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @FelixKling look at: https://www.debuggex.com/r/Qn9hhxhKXHczb8FQ - `.*?` matched `baz,bar`, cause else there is no result. (Just meaning: `.*?,` does NOT exculde the `,` from beeing matched by `.*?` - which is one of the most reasons, people are using `.*?` (match between).

Comment: @dognose: But that's not a case of `.*?,`, that's a case of `.*?,foo` ;) And it's still lazy. But I see that my first comment wasn't very precise. I should have said *"[...] find the shortest possible match that satisfies the whole expression"*. Point taken :)

Comment: That's correct: *that satisfies the expression* (!) - Most the time people are assuming that `(.*?),` will not match the `,`, cause then it's not the *shortest match possible*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try greedy way to match at most possible

```
.*,
```

> I need to exclude the last comma from the match

Try with Positive Lookahead

```
.*(?=,)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rI6yA4/14)

Answer (score 1):

Use this (see [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/14)):

```
.*(?<!,)
```

**Explanation**

- The `.*` matches the whole string
- The negative lookbehind `(?<!,)` asserts that what precedes is not a comma, forcing the engine to backtrack if needed

Answer (score 0):

You can use this lookahead based regex to match text until last comma:

```
.*?,(?![^,]*,)
```

Comment: What's the opposite of this - match all text *after* the last comma?